# Administrate - Rails 4 | `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'admin_root'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, routes

=> After deploying my rails app on Heroku

=> I cannot access to my admin at mysite.heroku.com/admin

--

I run heroku logs

The error : **Invalid route name, already in use: 'admin_root'**

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:549:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'admin_root'  (ArgumentError)
```

And **You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option**

```
 2016-10-24T13:43:56.930010+00:00 app[web.1]: You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
```

--

This is my config/routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
  get '/agence' => 'pages#agence'
  get '/methode' => 'pages#methode'
  get 'projets' => 'projet#index'
  get 'projets/:slug' => 'projet#show', as: 'projet'
  get '/article' => 'article#index'
  get '/article/:slug' => 'article#show', as: 'articles'
  get '/contact' => 'pages#contact'
  get '/mentionslegales' => 'pages#mentionslegales'


  namespace :admin do
    resources :projets
    resources :articles
    resources :users
    # get '/'  => 'projets#index'
    root to: "projets#index"

  end

  if defined?(DashboardManifest)
  namespace :admin do
    DashboardManifest::DASHBOARDS.each do |dashboard_resource|
      resources dashboard_resource
    end

    root controller: DashboardManifest::ROOT_DASHBOARD, action: :index
  end
end
```

--

Rake routes :

```
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
              root GET    /                                  pages#index
            agence GET    /agence(.:format)                  pages#agence
           methode GET    /methode(.:format)                 pages#methode
           projets GET    /projets(.:format)                 projet#index
            projet GET    /projets/:slug(.:format)           projet#show
           article GET    /article(.:format)                 article#index
          articles GET    /article/:slug(.:format)           article#show
           contact GET    /contact(.:format)                 pages#contact
   mentionslegales GET    /mentionslegales(.:format)         pages#mentionslegales
     admin_projets GET    /admin/projets(.:format)           admin/projets#index
                   POST   /admin/projets(.:format)           admin/projets#create
  new_admin_projet GET    /admin/projets/new(.:format)       admin/projets#new
 edit_admin_projet GET    /admin/projets/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/projets#edit
      admin_projet GET    /admin/projets/:id(.:format)       admin/projets#show
                   PATCH  /admin/projets/:id(.:format)       admin/projets#update
                   PUT    /admin/projets/:id(.:format)       admin/projets#update
                   DELETE /admin/projets/:id(.:format)       admin/projets#destroy
    admin_articles GET    /admin/articles(.:format)          admin/articles#index
                   POST   /admin/articles(.:format)          admin/articles#create
 new_admin_article GET    /admin/articles/new(.:format)      admin/articles#new
edit_admin_article GET    /admin/articles/:id/edit(.:format) admin/articles#edit
     admin_article GET    /admin/articles/:id(.:format)      admin/articles#show
                   PATCH  /admin/articles/:id(.:format)      admin/articles#update
                   PUT    /admin/articles/:id(.:format)      admin/articles#update
                   DELETE /admin/articles/:id(.:format)      admin/articles#destroy
       admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)             admin/users#index
                   POST   /admin/users(.:format)             admin/users#create
    new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)         admin/users#new
   edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)    admin/users#edit
        admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)         admin/users#show
                   PATCH  /admin/users/:id(.:format)         admin/users#update
                   PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)         admin/users#update
                   DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)         admin/users#destroy
        admin_root GET    /admin(.:format)                   admin/projets#index
```

I don't understand this error and how to resolve it.
I already read all posts about this error but can't find the solution..

Comment: Remove the first namespace admin block if you're updating the site to use administrate.

Comment: Try moving your second `admin_root` block above the first block the routes file.

Comment: @j-dexx if I remove first namespace admin block, I will not have admin anymore.

Comment: @meshpi I tried, nothing has changed

Comment: All works fine in local, but i get error 500 online. If I withdraw the line root to: "projet#index, then the website works well again except the admin.

Comment: i think `root controller: DashboardManifest::ROOT_DASHBOARD, action: :index` create problem

Comment: also check your local repo status does it contain code which need to push on heroku

Comment: Thank you Uzaif ! You put me on the right track to find the solution ! It was the lines: " if defined?(DashboardManifest)
  namespace :admin do
    DashboardManifest::DASHBOARDS.each do |dashboard_resource|
      resources dashboard_resource
    end

    root controller: DashboardManifest::ROOT_DASHBOARD, action: :index
  end" who need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was to with draw theses lines from routes.rb :

```
     if defined?(DashboardManifest)
  namespace :admin do
    DashboardManifest::DASHBOARDS.each do |dashboard_resource|
      resources dashboard_resource
    end

    root controller: DashboardManifest::ROOT_DASHBOARD, action: :index
  end
end
```